# Get rectangles instead of text in geoserver legend

Tags: gis, geoserver, wms

I am using Geoserver to produce WMS layers. I am from Georgia (Country not US state), so we need to have text in our language. We use utf-8 characters, but in WMS Legend get rectangles instead of text. In pevious version of geoserver it worked properly.

here is code of SLD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>უძრავი ძეგლები</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>uZravi Zeglebi</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Name>კულტურული მემკვიდრეობის ობიექტი</Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsLike wildCard="%" singleChar="#" escape="!">
              <ogc:PropertyName>status</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>კულტურული მემკვიდრეობის ობიექტი%</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsLike>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
         <Fill>
           <CssParameter name="fill">#ff6e6e</CssParameter>
         </Fill>
       </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
        <Name>kulturuli memkvidreobis dzegli</Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsLike wildCard="%" singleChar="#" escape="!">
              <ogc:PropertyName>status</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>კულტურული მემკვიდრეობის ძეგლი%</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsLike>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
         <Fill>
           <CssParameter name="fill">#8d1818</CssParameter>
         </Fill>
       </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
        <Name>obieqti statusis gareshe</Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsLike wildCard="%" singleChar="#" escape="!">
              <ogc:PropertyName>status</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>ობიექტი სტატუსის გარეშე%</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsLike>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
         <Fill>
           <CssParameter name="fill">#58ceeb</CssParameter>
         </Fill>
       </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

[image: rectangles instead of text]

I make setting to utf-8, everywhere find such settings.

Comment: Is Geoserver launched with UTF8? (JVM parameter `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`)

Comment: Does the font used in the legend have Georgian characters in it? I have no idea what font is used and if you can change it